# How to define FOREIGN KEY constraint in mysql in my case not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

I need to know about how to declare foreign key in mysql and how it works. Here's one sample 
first table contains `name`, `age` the second table refer the first tables `name`. While I run this, I receive `error` only.

```
<?php
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","12345");
$sql="USE new";
$conn->query($sql);
$sql="CREATE TABLE test(name varchar(20),age integer)";
$conn->query($sql);
$sql="CREATE TABLE test2(name varchar(10),FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES test     (name)";
if($conn->query($sql)==true)
{
    header('Locaton:test3.html');
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Foreign key docs ==> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: The idea of using names as Foreign key.. God plz no..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreign key must refrence from a Primary key then use a primary key on name,

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE test(name varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,age integer)";
```

and also change on

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE test2(name varchar(10),FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES test(name))";
```

if your `name` field have chance to duplicate then take one another field `id` and use it to reference.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `)` parenthesis at the end

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE test2(name varchar(10),FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES test (name))";
```

Answer (score 1):

FOREIGN KEY constraint defined at the **Column level**

#### Query

```
   $sql="CREATE TABLE test2(name varchar(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES test(name))";
```

---

FOREIGN KEY constraint defined at the **Table level**

#### Query

```
   $sql="CREATE TABLE test2(
                name varchar(10), 
                FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES test(name)
   )";
```

Check this reference [**URL**](http://way2tutorial.com/sql/sql_foreign_key_constraint.php). Both way you can do.

Comment: url reference i add check it.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you must use InnoDB when using foreign keys. Unless you have InnoDB as default, you need to specify the table type when creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE test(name varchar(20) primary key,age integer) engine=innodb;
CREATE TABLE test2(name varchar(10) primary key,FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES test     (name)) engine=innodb;
```

Also note that the you foreign keys need to be referencing indexed columns. Using primary key is one way to achieve this.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use and what error do you get? Above works fine with MySQL 5.5.25.

Comment: i am using server xampp 1.8.3 with mysql version 5.6.16..error is second table not created and no error message i am created using php code

Comment: Are you sure that the referenced column in first table is indexed - i.e. did you drop/create the table with index or primary key? Try var_dump($conn->error) after the error occures.